# Custom animations with makeCustomAnimation not working on some devices

Tags: android, android-animation

I've a problem with custom animations. Code below works fine with API 25 android emulator, but displays no animation on physical device API 23.

**Activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewClass.class);
intent.putExtra("data", data);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    Bundle options = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.slide_in_from_right,R.anim.slide_out_to_left).toBundle();
    startActivityForResult(intent,101,options);
}
```

**slide_in_from_right**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_to_left**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Solved. Problem was with physical device settings. Always make sure that 'Settings' -> 'Developer options' -> 'Transition animation scale' is not set to 'Animation is off' :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

### Create a file in res\anim\slide_out_to_left.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:duration="500"
         android:fromXDelta="0"
         android:toXDelta="-100%p" 
     />
   </set>
```

### Create a file in  res\anim\slide_in_from_right

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate
   android:duration="500"
   android:fromXDelta="0"
   android:toXDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

> this work in all version

Comment: Thanks for your help, but problem was with physical device settings, not the animation itself :)